# return django view to template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want have template tag...

There is some view and template ( `named X` ), when i call this view, return some html

for example

```
<h1>hi</h1>
```

In index of test application, i want when call template tag in template of this view, template tag return html of `named X`

for example

```
<h2>test</h2>
{% template_Tag_return_x_view %}
```

result

```
<h2>test</h2>
<h1>hi</h1>
```

whats is best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reuse your view's logic in several places it maybe it easier to turn the view into an [inclusion tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

It's more flexible than a simple `include` as you can specify parameters that influence the output.

Comment: i saw inclusion but how i can return special view in inclusion ?

Comment: Maybe you should explain better what your view does. My point is: If you want to get the same results that your view renders in several places of you application you are probably better of to transfrom your view into an inclusion (or more complex) template tag.

Comment: i must call view in inclusion tag and that view want request, how import this view without request?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the [`include` template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

Comment: @ bradley I saw this, but its only template... i want only send view argument not all return argument. how? tnx